# Django 1.7 where to put the code to add Groups programmatically?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have been trying to find the answer in the Django Auth docs, but can not seem to find what I am looking for.

The problem I am having is, when I define the code for adding Groups (same as Groups in the admin page):

```
#read_only
group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='read_only')   
if created:
    group.permissions.add(can_read_campaign)
    logger.info('read_only_user Group created')
#standard
group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='standard_user') 
if created:
    group.permissions.add(can_edit_users)
    logger.info('standard_user Group created')
#admin
group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='admin_user') 
if created:
    group.permissions.add(can_edit_campaign, can_edit_users)
    logger.info('admin_user Group created')
```

When I have run this code in models.py and **init**.py and they both give me this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady
```

I presume this is due to the Model/**init** trying to insert things into the django app/admin too early?

How can I add these Groups programmatically?

EDIT:

This is not a duplicate question, this was actually adding permission and groups within the models during setup of the project, rather than through the shell.

I have solved this issues, by using signals and receivers (django modules).

I added the code to create the permissions/groups into it's own function and decorated this with a receiver (post_migrate), which will run this function after migrations are complete, removing this error.

```
@receiver(post_migrate)
def init_groups(sender, **kwargs):
    #permission and group code goes here
```

Comment: You need to call the [`setup()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#application-registry) function. I would close this as a duplicate - let us know if it is really more than that.

Comment: Hi @alecxe this was not a duplicate question, i have provided an edit for you.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I was recommended [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) way to do it:

Create a fake migration in the appropriate module:

```
python manage.py makemigrations --empty yourappname
```

Open up the file that was created, which should look like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models, migrations

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('yourappname', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
    ]
```

And add your code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models, migrations

def add_group_permissions():
    #read_only
    group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='read_only')   
    if created:
        group.permissions.add(can_read_campaign)
        logger.info('read_only_user Group created')

    #standard
    group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='standard_user') 
    if created:
        group.permissions.add(can_edit_users)
        logger.info('standard_user Group created')

    #admin
    group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='admin_user') 
    if created:
        group.permissions.add(can_edit_campaign, can_edit_users)
        logger.info('admin_user Group created')

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('yourappname', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(add_group_permissions),
    ]
```

Finally, run the migration:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

This is nice because you can deploy to Heroku or wherever and be sure it'll be applied, as it's just another migration.

Comment: Nice answer, very neat way to do it.

Comment: Just an improvement:
def create_group(name, perms=[]):
    group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name=name)
    if created:
        for perm in perms:
            group.permissions.add(perm)
        logger.info("Group \"" + name + "\" created")

Comment: In Django 1.8 I had to add two things to this answer: `from django.contrib.auth.models import Group` at the top or it complains about Group not being defined. and then the function definition needed two params:  `def add_group_permissions(apps, schema_editor):`.

Comment: In django 1.9.5, trying to fetch permissions during migrations causes an error for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38491215/programmatically-creating-a-group-cant-access-permissions-from-migration/38491679#38491679 .

Answer (score 5):

Combining @Robert Grant and [this](https://www.geekrant.org/2014/04/19/programmatically-create-django-security-groups/) I was able to do it like:

```
python manage.py makemigrations --empty yourappname
```

And then:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission
from django.db import models, migrations
import logging


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

campaign_group_permissions = {
  "Campaign Manager": [
    "add_campaign",
    "change_campaign",
    "delete_campaign",
    "view_campaign",
    "add_campaignsms",
    "add_sending",
    "change_sending",
    "view_sending"
  ]
}


def add_group_permissions():
    # See https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23422
    db_alias = schema_editor.connection.alias
    try:
        emit_post_migrate_signal(2, False, 'default')
    except TypeError:  # Django < 1.8
        emit_post_migrate_signal([], 2, False, 'default', db_alias)

    for group in campaign_group_permissions:
        role, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name=group)
        logger.info(f'{group} Group created')
        for perm in campaign_group_permissions[group]:
            role.permissions.add(Permission.objects.get(codename=perm))
            logger.info(f'Permitting {group} to {perm}')
        role.save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('yourappname', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(add_group_permissions),
    ]
```

**Note:** this works on Django 3.x, but I'm pretty sure it will work for Django 1.7 as well.

Answer (score 5):

@Ruloweb's fantastic response almost worked for me, but I had to make a couple tweaks to get it to work in Django 3.1 with multiple apps.

First, I needed to add arguments to the add_group_permissions() function. I also needed to import the emit_post_migration_signal:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission
from django.core.management.sql import emit_post_migrate_signal # <-- Added this
from django.db import models, migrations
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

public_group_permissions = {
  "Your permission group name here": ['your permissions here']
}

def add_group_permissions(apps, schema_editor): # <-- updated this

    # See https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23422
    db_alias = schema_editor.connection.alias

    try:
        emit_post_migrate_signal(2, False, 'default')
    except TypeError:  # Django < 1.8
        emit_post_migrate_signal([], 2, False, 'default', db_alias)

    for group in public_group_permissions:
        role, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name=group)
        logger.info(f'{group} Group created')
        for perm in public_group_permissions[group]:
            role.permissions.add(Permission.objects.get(codename=perm))
            logger.info(f'Permitting {group} to {perm}')
        role.save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('your_app_name', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(add_group_permissions),
    ]
```