# Programmatically creating a group : Can't access permissions from migration

Tags: django, permissions, migration

After seeing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25803284/3156085), I tried to create my own group at project setup with this migration :

```
from django.db import migrations
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission

def create_group(apps, schema_editor):
    group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='thing_managers')
    if created:
        add_thing = Permission.objects.get(codename='add_thing')
        group.permissions.add(add_thing)
        group.save()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('main', '0002_auto_20160720_1809'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_group),
    ]
```

But I got the following error :

```
django.contrib.auth.models.DoesNotExist: Permission matching query does not exist.
```

Here is my model :

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    pass
```

Why can't I do that? How could I solve this?

I use **django 1.9**.

Comment: First of all, you should not import your the models from `from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission`, but using `apps.get_model("some_app", "model_name")`. And 2nd the error is pretty clear - you don't have a permission with `codename='add_thing'`

Answer (score 3):

From [this Django ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23422), here's what worked for me in Django 3.0.4 and apparently will work in >=1.9:

```
from django.core.management.sql import emit_post_migrate_signal

def create_group(apps, schema_editor):
    # Ensure permissions and content types have been created.
    db_alias = schema_editor.connection.alias
    emit_post_migrate_signal(2, False, db_alias)
    # Now the content types and permissions should exist

    Permission = apps.get_model('auth', 'Permission')
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Permissions are created in a `post_migrate` signal. They don't exist the first time migrations are run after a new model is added. It is probably easiest to run the `post_migrate` [signal handler](https://github.com/django/django/blob/09d38746bafa4b3dd9fc21ffab822ed53087d794/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py#L400) manually:

```
from django.contrib.auth.management import create_permissions

def create_group(apps, schema_editor):
    for app_config in apps.get_app_configs():
        create_permissions(app_config, apps=apps, verbosity=0)

    group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='thing_managers')
    if created:
        add_thing = Permission.objects.get(codename='add_thing')
        group.permissions.add(add_thing)
        group.save()
```

`create_permissions` checks for existing permissions, so this won't create any duplicates.

Comment: But in this case, how was the answer to another post I linked supposed to work? Perhaps the permissions creation process changed since 1.7?

I tried your solution but I still have the same error.

Comment: For which model are the permissions you're trying to fetch? Is the model created in the same app, in a previous migration? Otherwise you might have to [add a dependency](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#accessing-models-from-other-apps) to the app where the model is defined.

Comment: For the `Thing` model in my `main` app. The model is created in the models.py file, I didn't touch to migrations before this.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is call the update_permissions command before try to append a permission

```
from django.core.management import call_command

def update_permissions(schema, group):
    call_command('update_permissions')


operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(update_permissions, reverse_code=migrations.RunPython.noop),
        migrations.RunPython(create_group),
    ]
```

And as was commented don't import Group and Permission models use:

```
Group = apps.get_model("auth","Group")
Permission = apps.get_model("auth","Permission")
```

Comment: Note that this command is not part of the core Django, but of django-extensions lib