# What is the best way to prepopulate Groups table and permissions for it at application startup?

Tags: django, orm

My goal is:

- to have created  custom Groups and populated with permissions for specific models. All that immediately after or during application starts

Question:

- What is the most appropriate way to achieve that?

For example my custom group is MY_CUSTOM_GROUP and i want to add `change` and `view` permissions for Model `Book` to that group

Comment: A fixture would be appropriate for your use-case https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/initial-data/

Comment: @Iain Shelvington
And why not to write manual migration? What is the advantage of fixture over manual migration?

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into that problem myself. The [standard way](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/initial-data/) to do it is either by creating a custom migration or through fixtures. Groups and permissions added through a custom migration will be available without any additional commands. The downside might be that the process of migrations rebuild will now be more complicated (I am a noob at django too, so please correct me if I'm wrong here). Fixtures require running a manage.py command to prepopulate the database, but they come with the advantage of being completely decoupled from migrations.

Comment: This question has a useful example of making a custom migration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25024795/django-1-7-where-to-put-the-code-to-add-groups-programmatically